# How to choose bowling run up and action?

Tags: cricket, technique, training

I'm a **fast bowler**, but What I do is: I'd changed my bowling action many times which results in not getting a good rhythm. So please tell me how to choose the bowling run up and action?

My height is about 5.9 and lean. Currently I bowl like Aussie cricketer **Ryan Harris**.

Answer (score 3):

With your action, go back to whatever feels natural.  Don't think about what your doing too much just bowl, you'll need to practice it for a while to get it consistent.

For your run up, I'd experiment to find something that works for you.  You want to be comfortable and balanced when you reach the crease so try different lengths of run up until you find the one that suits you.

Ideally, you have to find these things for yourself, other people can advise on how to find it or fine tune what you have but you should try and work your own basic action and run up out for yourself as this will help you throughout your cricket career.  Good Luck and have patience with the process!

Answer (score -4):

A high arm bowling action is better than a round arm bowling action as you get more bounce and swing.just choose an action which doesn't break your momentum which you gain by run up.make your shoulders broad and strong. Hit the ball on to the pitch with power.make use of your wrist to generate more pace.LIKE YOU CAN SEE SHOIAB AKHTAR HE GENERATES EXTRA PACE WITH HIS WRIST.JUST PRACTICE AND WORK HARD.BEST OF LUCK.